# CONCATENATEX Inside IN Operator POWER BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I'm having a problem testing a POWER BI Measure. I'm trying to concatenate all the selected value in my splicer and want to use it as a values for my IN operator. My code looks like this.

```
var concats = CONCATENATEX (VALUES( 'Year'[Year] ) ,  """" & [Year] & """" , ", ")
return
CALCULATE(
    COUNTA('End Life'[Category]),
    'End Life'[EOLYear] IN { concats  }
   
)
```

If I will try to manual input say for sample: "2021","2022", it will work but if the Concatenatex result it would not work.
This code always results to blank, I am doing it wrong or I am missing something?
Please do help me with it.

Thanks.

Comment: Is that JavaScript? If so, I think you've stumbled upon a very strange (mis)feature of JavaScript called automatic semicolon insertion. If that is the case, you should make your code look like `return CALCULATE(…);` and so on.

Comment: It's not a JavaScript, it's a power bi desktop application

Comment: I mean, is the query written in JavaScript?

Comment: hmmm I don't if power BI measure is created in Javascript. But here is my code creating this measure:

Count of EOLYear for Current Year = 
var concats = CONCATENATEX (VALUES( 'Year'[Year] ) ,  """" & [Year] & """" , ", ")
return
CALCULATE(
 COUNTA('End Life'[Category]),
    'End Life'[EOLYear] IN { concats  }
   
)

Comment: That isn't going to work. DAX (the query language used here) doesn't permit any kind of dynamic expression evaluation, so you can't use your `concats` variable in an `IN` that way. It looks like you rather want to `UNION` your slicer table with your fixed row and use `TREATAS` to filter (look at examples for [`CONTAINS`](https://dax.guide/contains/)).

Comment: Why not simply create a relationship between `'Year'[Year]` and `'End Life'[EOLYear]`, then your measure can become a simple `COUNTA ( 'End Life'[Category] )`

Comment: I have my reason for not creating a relationship Olly

Comment: What is the reason? If necessary, you could create an inactive relationship, then your measure could become `CALCULATE ( COUNTA ( 'End Life'[Category] ), USERELATIONSHIP ( 'Year'[Year], 'End Life'[EOLYear] ) )`